# JMS queue message read error

Tags: jms

I am workig with jms queue, Connection was creating properly with jms queue, but when started reading message from JMS queue,first time it was not read any message but on second attempt (in loop second iteration) message will retrieved .
example: On i=1 in shown in below code if(message instanceof TextMessage) was returning false but on i=2 returns ture and we are able to read message.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
            message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(100);
            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                messageProcessed++;
                String msgValue = (String) message.getText();
                System.out.println(msgValue);
                XMLDomFromString(msgValue);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable, you have a timeout of 100 miliseconds, which might be less than just the round trip time to the broker in some unlucky cases.

Comment: after increasing time out to 1000 milliseconds its working fine. like :message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(1000);

Comment: Well, you need to check if .receive() returns NULL, which indicates a timeout. There could be a thousand reasons why you don't receive a message within 1 second, and you should decide what to do in that case.

Comment: Is there a reason for iterating 7 times in the 'for' loop? If your application design allows you may want to look at using consumer.receive() which would wait till a message is available.

Comment: iteration 7 is only for understanding purpose, And your architecture does not allow consumer to wait for unlimited time. we are using loop for batch processing..   for (int i = 1; i <= JMSQueueReadBatchSize && message instanceof TextMessage; i++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please increase the wait time because some time due to network delay you are not able to read the message, Example:
 message = (TextMessage) consumer.receive(1000);
increase the waiting time from 100 to 1000 and problem is solved now.